# How to make OSGI EventAdmin handle events in multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, osgi

I am developing OSGI project. There are lots of services uses event admin, sending and handling events. And it seems that event admin handles events in a single thread. When a handleEvent function is activated, any other handle event function wont starts until running handleEvent function exits. I tested it Thread.sleep function.

I wonder if there are any configuration or parameter to make event admin to handle events in a multi-threaded fashion.

I am using eclipse neon 3 and equinox comes with it.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the event admin impl you use. For [felix eventadmin](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-event-admin.html) the default is to use 20 threads and it is configureable.

You also should use eventAdmin.postEvent to ensure async delivery.

Comment: I am using eclipse neon 3 and equinox comes with it. And i used postEvent.

Answer (score 1):

The spec provides leeway in the number of threads used. However, there is one guarantee that can be costly. Events must be delivered in order to a given handler. This constraints parallel delivery. You can register a service property `event.delivery=async.unordered` that will remove this constrain for a handler and allows the Event Admin more leeway in delivering events.

I find it rather hard to believe that the Equinox version would use only one thread ...

To learn more about Event Admin, read the tutorial [OSGi Event Admin – Publish & Subscribe](http://blog.vogella.com/2017/05/16/osgi-event-admin-publish-subscribe/)